# Environment considerations for displaying a pdf in an iframe

Tags: pdf, iframe, browser, adobe

I have a page with an iframe who's src attribute is assigned the path of a pdf file. I can verify it all works on my dev environment and I'm even testing this with the following mark-up:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="hello.pdf" height="500px" width="500px"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This displays fine, but as soon as I move it to the test environment it's invoking the download dialog OR freezing the browser.

**What I've Tried:**

- I've tried this with numerous pdf readers (including non-Adobe
  readers).
- I've tried every pdf reader configuration setting I can see that would be of any relevance.
- I've also tweaked the security settings of the browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have performed some test on my side and it is fully working with a PDF. For me it is either related to your browser setting regarding management of pdf file (or application/pdf mimetype etc..) or either to your application server setting regarding handling of pdf file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your response. I've just found this article > http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305836. I've tried to switch to the 32 bit of IE and it did work, but still switching to 32 bit IE on test hasn't worked.